# Sql Server 2014 Instance

Tags: sql-server, instance, ssms, server-name

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.
When opening the program I'm prompted to enter Server type, Server name and authentication credentials. Apparently I do not have any server instances to be able to continue. See screenshot:

[image: SSMS Connect to Server dialog]

My aim is to create a local database, but for that I need something to input as server name (I need to create a server instance, correct me if I'm wrong).
Help is appreciated.

Comment: To create a local database you need to install the server components, Management Studio just lets you manage local or remote installations of SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

*If* you've installed SQL Server on any computer, whether it is a 'server' class system or a 'PC', you can connect to it using the host name or ip address of that machine. SQL Server Management Studio alone is not enough.

So install SQL Server (the database engine), and then connect to an instance. It is called the 'management studio', and in order to 'manage' something, you first have to install it.

Comment: Could you provide me with a step by step guide and links where to get anything that is needed if possible, thanks

Comment: I would try [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/) first to get the hang of it. There is a lot you can do with it already. MSDN is quite complete on every step you need, just check the page under the link.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about the actual "SQL Server".  Management Studio merely connects to a SQL server via connection string.

To create a SQL Server instance:

1. Start Menu > All Programs> Microsoft SQL Server...> Configuration Tools
2. Click "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
3. In Left pane, select "SQL Server" and create your instance

If you're missing the node, "SQL Server", you might not have the license.  In that case, your IT support might be expecting you to make remote connections to dev servers, instead of working on a local db.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, if you have done installation correctly, your hostname is your server name. From screenshot shared, I can see , you are using windows server authentication and if it is so, your username should be hostname\username. You need to try to connect with hostname, if you are good with the installation.